# how to check row number while importing data

Tags: mysql, select, insert

We have database table 'field_data_body' and we are using 'insert into ... select from' mysql command to insert data into 'field_data_body' from another table.

Table structure:
[image]

In our database table, delta column is used to differentiate same record. For example,

[image]

In above exmaple, both row has same data except different value of delta.

How can we set delta while inserting data into database table?

I have search in google and some other questions in stack exchange but did not find solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put your query?

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 queries for that.

1. insert into tablename (col1, col2, ..) Values (value1, value2, ..);
2. insert into tablename (delta) Values (value) where entity_type = 'node';